# SP 2010 developer Dash board query

Tags: service-applications

To increase the performance of the site, can we disable the SharePoint 2010 developer dash board using powershell ??

Answer (score 3):

To toggle developer dashboard

```
$service = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
$addsetting =$service.DeveloperDashboardSettings
#Use On Off or OnDemand
$addsetting.DisplayLevel = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDeveloperDashboardLevel]::Off
$addsetting.Update()
```

Comment: Thanks..If we disable Developer dashboard, Is performance increase ?? and any drawbacks if disable the same

Comment: Developer Dashboard should not be activated on production servers in the first place

Comment: if disable the developer dashboard in production, i think performace may increase right ? please clarify

Comment: No, developer dashboard is used to view diagnostic info which a developer can use to debug various aspects of a page (like tracing performance issues). It should be turned off for prod environment and only turned on if something goes wrong and you need to look at debugging info.

Answer (score 1):

Developer dashboard should be enabled only when you see some unexpected behavior (delay in loading webpart etc) and want to see what part of page is taking more time.

Enabling it will surely affect performance of your SharePoint site since it will have to load the calculations.

It is always better to keep it off when everything is well :)

Regards,
Sudhir

Comment: In case you feel that you may want to view Developer dashboard very frequently,  you can keep the developer dashboard settings to OnDemand.

Comment: Thank u.Actually my central admin the developer dash board is enabled(i can view icon rigt side top corner)..but how can valdiate in the Sites(i cannot see that icon in portals)..any otehr confirmation tecnique ? please share with me..i will check with my entire sites

Answer (score 0):

If needed, You can enable developer dashboard on demand only.

See Section **5. Developer Dashboard** here for details:

http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2012/05/25/troubleshooting-sharepoint-2010-tools-techniques/